# 3D PLOT OF AN ORBIT

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab, programming

Suppose you have an orbit an and you know the 6 parameters $a,e,i,\Omega,\omega,\theta$ that characterize the orbit. 
In my case:

- $a=9661.07 \text{ km}$
- $e=0.0841816$
- $i=23.6047^\circ$
- $\Omega=29.7304^\circ$
- $\omega=48.3429^\circ$
- $\theta=81.269^\circ$

Now you want to have a 3D plot to visualize the orbit with a good render using MATLAB (or MATHEMATICA). My question is: is there such a way to do this? Could someone suggest me a good MATLAB code to have this rappresentation?
Thank you vary much for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of algorithms online that allow you to transform between orbital elements and $3$D orbits, [this](https://downloads.rene-schwarz.com/download/M001-Keplerian_Orbit_Elements_to_Cartesian_State_Vectors.pdf) document is particularly useful

It takes as inputs

- Sem-major axis $a$
- Eccentricity $e$
- Argument of periapsis $\omega$
- Longitude of ascending node $\Omega$
- Inclination $i$
- Mean anomaly at epoch $t_0$ $M_0 = M(t_0)$

and produces the cartesian position ${\bf r}$ and velocity vectors $\dot{\bf r}$ at epoch $t$